# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Am trying to enable node-to-node and client-to-node ssl encrytion in Datastax dse 3.2.3. First I tried to enable node-to-node it worked fine and started with out any error and then I added the client-to-node encryption options in the cassandra.yaml file, then it started throwing errors to me

```
ERROR [Thrift:1] 2014-01-15 16:22:22,628 TNegotiatingServerTransport.java (line 524) Failed to open server transport.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.readUntilEof(TPreviewableTransport.java:79)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.preview(TPreviewableTransport.java:55)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:189)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:517)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 9 more
DEBUG [WRITE-/x.x.x.x] 2014-01-15 16:22:27,586 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 294) attempting to connect to /x.x.x.x
DEBUG [WRITE-/x.x.x.x] 2014-01-15 16:22:28,508 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 294) attempting to connect to /x.x.x.x
ERROR [Thrift:2] 2014-01-15 16:22:32,926 TNegotiatingServerTransport.java (line 524) Failed to open server transport.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.readUntilEof(TPreviewableTransport.java:79)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TPreviewableTransport.preview(TPreviewableTransport.java:55)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:189)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:517)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 9 more
```

My cassandra.yaml file looks like this.

```
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: all
    keystore: /path/to/.keystore
    keystore_password: xxxxx
    truststore: /path/to/.truststore
    truststore_password: xxxxx



client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    keystore: /path/to/.keystore
    keystore_password: xxxxx
    truststore: /path/to/.truststore
    truststore_password: xxxxx
    protocol: ssl
    store_type: JKS
    cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

Answer (score 3):

This error means that you have a client which is attempting to open an unencrypted connection.

Comment: Its a brand new cluster and no writes or reads are going on in the cluster.

Comment: Something must be attempting to connect, as evidenced by the stacktrace as node to node messaging doesn't use thrift

Comment: I think the problem is related to cqlsh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489774/cqlsh-with-client-to-node-ssl-encryption