# Cqlsh with client to node SSL encryption

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, cqlsh

Am trying to enable client to node SSL encryption in my DSE server.

My cqlshrc file looks like below

```
 [connection]
 hostname = 127.0.0.1
 port = 9160
 factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory

 [ssl]
 certfile = /path/to/dse_node0.cer
 validate = true ;; Optional, true by default.

 [certfiles] ;; Optional section, overrides the default certfile in the [ssl] section.
 1.2.3.4 = /path/to/dse_node0.cer
```

When I tried to login into cqlsh shell then am getting the below error

```
Connection error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:9160
```

Comment: is the rpc_address parameter in your cassandra.yaml set to something other than 127.0.0.1 (like the ip address of the host?) If so you should use that in the hostname setting within cqlshrc

Comment: rpc_address is set to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Did you find a solution to this by yourself? I would be interested...

Comment: It works only if you make validate = false in ssl options.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes I hope one of these solutions is helpful.

1) The certificate in the ssl section is not the same as (derived from) the keystore specified in the cassandra.yaml file.

Solution: generate a certificate from the keystore used in the cassandra.yaml file and place that in the location pointed to in your cqlshrc file.

2) The certificate file or keystore is changed after starting the node. Cassandra loads a copy of the certificate when it starts up.

Solution: Restart the node.

3) In the certfiles section 127.0.0.1 is over-ridden by the wrong certificate

Solution: use the correct certificate or drop the 127.0.0.1 entry.

Comment: I used the same certificate file for cassandra and cqlsh. I started cassandra with new certificate file ( I tried restarting DSE too still the error persist ). I changed the loopback address to ipaddress still I got the same error.